# Why does ContinueWith appear to be blocking and / or running tasks sequentially

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I'm confused as to how ContinueWith works, it appears to block the ThreadPool and runs tasks sequentially. Take the following code example I have written:

```
         var items = new List<int>();

         for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
         {
             items.Add(i);
         }

         Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
             {
               Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                 {

                 }).ContinueWith(t =>
                 {
                     if (item < 50)
                     {
                         System.Console.WriteLine("Blocking in {0}", item.ToString());
                         var x = SomeLongRunningDatabaseCall(10001);
                     }
                     System.Console.WriteLine("Item {0}", item);
                 });
             });
```

The purpose of the code was to mirror a suspected thread blocking problem I had on a production application. To my surprise with the above code I found the issue seems to be with my use of ContinueWith. What's interesting is if I set the option TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning on ContinueWith it runs the tasks asynchronously without blocking, I've also done this in my production app and this has fixed the issue.

However, I'm really confused and want to better understand why the ContinueWith statement without the option TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning is causing the tasks to block or appear to run sequentially even though I'm invoking a new thread per iteration of items. The only thing I can think of is that ContinueWith is not running in the thread that the antecedent task was executed in but on the main thread which could be causing the block.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

## Update

Also what's interesting is that if I replace

```
    SomeLongRunningDatabaseCall(10001)
```

with something like

```
    Thread.Sleep(600000)
```

it doesn't block however with a call to the database it does but since it's running in it's own thread there shouldn't be any blockage for the other tasks at least, since tasks > 50 don't call the database.

Comment: The call to `ContinueWith` almost certainly isn't blocking.  The actual operations may well be running sequentially; if they are, it's due to the nature of what they're doing, not how `ContinueWith` is implemented.  That's why you see `Sleep` calls being parallelized.

Comment: @Servy Ah, I see what you mean. How do you explain the fact that tasks > 50 don't run till the other tasks have completed considering that they are supposed to be running on separate threads. (I don't know if you've had a chance to see my update)

Comment: That's merely stating that some of the tasks appear to be waiting on others.  You cannot have an infinite degree of parallelism.  I certainly am not surprised that you can't have more than 50 parallel DB calls, nor would I expect there be performance benefits from any more running in parallel.

Comment: @Servy I see now, thanks. So by setting TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning on ContinueWith would you say that each thread is then running in a separate thread pool, hence why it appears as though there is no blocking.

Comment: It results in new threads being created, instead of using the thread pool at all.  If the thread pool is what's blocking you, then that would affect it.  If the blocking is coming from elsewhere, then it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread should be using it's own database connection object. Most database connections that I'm aware of do not support non-locking multi-threaded modes. In those database connections, it's not unusual for the threads to be blocked, since the single connection will execute calls sequentially rather than in parallel.

That being the case, making a Parallel.ForEach() may just end up borking your app, since a database connection is (relatively) expensive, and it's not feasible, really, to open up a whole bunch of database connections. It might be better to use a different pattern, for instance putting the `item` objects into a `ConcurrentQueue` or a `ConcurrentStack` and throwing 3-5 threads (or more - you'll have to experiment here) against this collection and letting these run until the stack or queue gets depleted. That way you can keep the number of instanced database connections to a safe number and still avoid that nasty blocking.

All of this leads me to think that using `Parallel.ForEach` for actual database execution (not talking about LINQ-to-SQL or EF here, but actual database connection calls, like `SqlCommand.Execute`) is probably sub-optimal.

EDIT: you don't have to use the old syntax for my suggestion. A clump of Tasks would do just as nicely.